# Use sockets to transmit a video from one PC to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to transmit a video frame by frame using sockets and then presenting it using open-cv. The code gets stuck after the first frame transfer. The first frame is displayed once i forcefully exits the transmit code.

Tried to add loops and remove loops . i eve tried to add delays between the transmission.

Server code

```
import socket, pickle
import os
import cv2
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
while 1:
data =b""
    while 1:
        packet = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not packet: break
        data += packet
    data_arr = pickle.loads(data)
    print("data")
    cv2.imshow('image',data_arr)
    print("cv2")
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):                  
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
conn.close()
```

Client Code

```
import socket
import pickle
import cv2
import os
import time

path = os.getcwd()
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
image = cv2.imread(path+"//example.jpg")
data_string = pickle.dumps(arr)
while 1:
    s.send(data_string)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: "*I have been trying to transmit a video frame by frame using sockets*": Where exactly is that? I only see you reading an image, pickling it in memory, and sending it.

Comment: It is being received in the Server code. "packet = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)" As the image packet is larger than the size it keeps checking until the whole packet is received. For now i am trying to send the same frame again and again.